# Ruby require a module in a module?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, module, mixins

I am using the SendGrid module (`require sendgrid-ruby`), but placing code like this everywhere is not very DRY.

```
client = SendGrid::Client.new(api_key: SENDGRID_KEY)
      mail = SendGrid::Mail.new do |m|
        m.to = 'js@lso.com'
        m.from = 'no-reply@gsdfdo.com'
        m.subject = 'Boo'
        m.html = " "
        m.text = " "
      end
```

My thought was create a module `MyModule` that would create a method called standardMail

```
module MyModule
    require 'sendgrid-ruby'
    def standardMail
          mail = SendGrid::Mail.new do |m|
            m.to = 'js@lso.com'
            m.from = 'no-reply@gsdfdo.com'
            m.subject = 'Boo'
            m.html = " "
            m.text = " "
          end
     return mail
    end 
end
```

Then can I just use `standardMail` (via `include MyModule`) to return the mail object setup and ready to go. My question is can you require a module in a module (**aka require sendgrid-ruby in my custom module**).

```
class Thing
  include MyModule

  def doMail
   mail = Thing.standardMail 
  end 
end
```

Comment: "include module in a module" and "require module in a module" are two very different things. In particular, `require MyModule` is not valid.

Comment: Fixed the question title

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you need a module in this case it would be much easier to extend the default behavior of Sendgrid:

```
class MyMailer < SendGrid::Mail
 def initialize(params)
    @to = 'js@lso.com'
    @from = 'no-reply@gsdfdo.com'
    @subject = 'Boo'
    @html = " "
    @text = " "

    super
  end
end
```

Or you can override directly:

```
class SendGrid::Mail
  def initialize(params)
    @to = 'js@lso.com'
    @from = 'no-reply@gsdfdo.com'
    @subject = 'Boo'
    @html = " "
    @text = " "

    super
  end
end
```

Comment: I am new to Ruby so didn't think of that. But I don't want all SendGrid::Mail to be overridden, just about 30 times in my app. There are another 10 uses that I don't use my standard to, from and subject. I guess using your code I would just use MyMailer in the 30 cases and the other 10 just use the official SendGrid::Mail as normal?

Comment: Then use the first example, it extends the mailer, but doesn't override its default functionality.

Answer (score -1):

There is no difference between:

```
module Foo
  require 'bar'
  # ...
end
```

and

```
require 'bar'
module Foo
  # ...
end
```

So, yes, you can require a <strike>module</strike> Ruby file inside a module, but there is little reason to do so.